# Insert content of div in to address bar

Tags: jquery

How would I go about inserting the contents of a `<div>` into the browsers address bar? Suppose I have:

```
<div id="content">bathroom</div>
```

How would I go about that? The site is a 1 page build with hashtags and JSON, trying to make the `#categorypage` URL play nicely with Google Analytics by inserting the title of the page that's in the content area in to the address bar so Google sees `.com#categorypage-bathroom`

Thanks.

EDIT:

The `controller.js` file uses

`$("#productPage_HeaderTitle").html(this.product.ProductName);`

and the category js file uses to direct to the product page

`$.mobile.changePage($("#productPage"), { transition: "fade" });`

I somehow need to add this.product.ProductName to #productPage

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
alert(document.URL+$('#content').html);
```

Comment: That's just going to give me an alert, not injecting anything in to the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.trigger').click(function() // Use class instead of ID
{
var data=$(this).text();
var url=window.location.href;
var to_url=url+"#"+data;
window.location.href=to_url;
});
```

Comment: Ok, to be more specific the content isn't pulled in with <a> tags - it's AJAX that pulls the content in. And there's a product catalogue of 10,000+ products - so not viable. Each page has a <div> with a title in, I would like to somehow get that content in to the address bar so to make the link unique (to GA that is) as opposed to having 1200 products that just show up in GA as /#bathroom. Thanks

Comment: Check the edited answer. But remember this will reload the page